# Solution of quadratic inequalities

Tags: inequality

I was solving quadratic inequality using algebra and here is what I get.

4-x²≥0

(2-x)(2+x)≥0 . Both factors should be positive (or negative)

Therefore

2-x≥0 and 2+x≥0 or 2-x≤0 and 2+x≤0

x≤2 and x≥-2 or x≥2 and x≤-2

-2≤x≤2 or 2≤x≤-2.

-2≤x≤2 is valid answer but 2≤x≤-2 is invalid. I expected both answers to be correct. Why do I get invalid answer. Is there any mistakes in my calculations?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The strategy is to find the zeros and make the so-called "sign chart." Divide the number line into three parts, broken apart at the zeros, and test the inequality in each region.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of using number line. But I was interested in algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists no $x$ such that $2-x$ and $2+x$ are both negative. Similarly, there exists no $x$ that satisfies $2 \leq x \leq -2$. This is why you get your 'invalid' answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

You got that$$-2\leqslant x\leqslant2\text{ or }2\leqslant x\leqslant-2,\tag1$$which is correct. But the pair of inequalities $2\leqslant x\leqslant-2$ never holds. So, the assertion $(1)$ is equivalent to $-2\leqslant x\leqslant2$. There is nothing invalid there.